# UIAlertView displays alert showing late than when required ios

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I am using UIAlertView to display alert and it is working for first time that when i click alert appears but when second time i do it then on clicking twice alert gets displayed instead of 1st click.

During secong time "visited full" gets printed on 1st click but alert appears on 2click, Why does this appear?Please help me to resolve.Thanks in advance

```
println("visited full")
var alert:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Video", message: "You have played all videos", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
  alert!.show()
```

Comment: That `var` should be a `let`. Are you sure you're doing this in the main thread?

Comment: I tried let but nothing changed but 1 thing i noticed is alert appears on 1st click but takes very much time. So i was clicking 2nd time. why is it so?

Comment: The let will not fix the problem. But you should pretty much always use `let` unless you need to actually change the value. Actually, you should be using `UIAlertController` like in the answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IF it doesn't work then try this may be this will work.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Video", message: "You have played all videos", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**EDIT**:
I think you can use it like this way too:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    var alert:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Video", message: "You have played all videos", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()
})
```

and for `UIAlertController`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Video", message: "You have played all videos", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: I have tried this one also before but same thing happens using UIAlertController.

Comment: @jalakpatel it sounds like you're trying to do this from a background thread. You need to do this in the main thread.

Comment: it is depending upon where you declaring this controller

Comment: Should i place alert part on main thread? and i have heard UIAlertController does not work with ios 7

Comment: @jalakpatel yes, UIAlertController is iOS8 only. You NEED to run UI stuff on the main thread.

Comment: I Edit the answer I think it may help you

Comment: So glad to come across this - I had exactly the same issue, never occurred to me it could be a threading issue. Now works fine - thanks